# Real random c# generator

Tags: c#-4.0

```
  Random ran = new Random();
  byte tmp = (byte)ran.Next(10);
```

Is there an alternative to this code?
It does not seem to have fully random behavior.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are multiple reasons for why this could occur.  One common problem is to create multiple instances of the `Random` class within a program.  When using the `Random` class you should only create one instance and generate numbers from that.  The article [Create better random numbers in C#](https://scottlilly.com/create-better-random-numbers-in-c/) has a good explanation of why and explains why not doing this could lead to a problem.

Another common scenario is accessing the `Random` class object from multiple threads.  `System.Random` is not thread safe (see the [Remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) of the documentation for `Random`) and thus can lead to unexpected and unwanted behavior. If using it in a multi-threaded environment then you need to be sure to use some form of locking to prevent multiple threads trying to generate random numbers at the same time.

For higher degrees of security and randomness you can use a cryptographically secure random number generator like
[System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx).  Note that using a more secure random number generator will incur a performance penalty in comparison with `System.Random`.

If you don't need something cryptographically secure, but still want something that is more "random" than the `Random` class you can explore using other PRNG's such as Mersenne Twister. There are lots of options, each with different characteristics and performance profiles.  Which you choose is heavily dependent on your goal.

Comment: No. The problem is instantiating a new Random instance for each Next() call. An often made mistake.

Comment: @Thorham - While that may be the case it cannot be construed from the question. The question is a simple snippet, it may be run only one time, maybe with each instantiation of the app, it's anyone's guess. I was acting off the assumption that the OP is __not__ creating a new `Random` object for each iteration of a loop or something like that.  Based off of one of the OPs comments I would also argue that my answer is in fact addressing the actual issue, that the result was not "Random" enough. They were running some sort of statistical analysis. For that you want a better random generator.

Comment: @Thorham - Also, I would highly doubt that this is the "wrong" answer since it is the one that the OP accepted. It may or may not be the best answer as I certainly could have expanded it more, but since the question was vague I tried to answer it in a more general fashion. But saying it is incorrect seems a bit of a reach. Without more code from the OP there is no way to diagnose the issue further, it may be they kept creating new instances, but could just as easily have been caused by using the same instance of `Random` in multiple threads, or maybe they just generated too many `4`'s.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. I'll remove the down vote, but you have to edit the answer (it won't let me otherwise). However, in general it's not a good idea to recommend the RNGCryptoServiceProvider. It's slow and potentially depletable. Linux's /dev/random and /dev/urandom are examples of this. When the system runs out of entropy, random will lock, and urandom will produce crappy quality numbers. If security isn't a thing, don't use crypto, unless you don't need many numbers. If statistical quality and speed are required (but not security), then implement something like PCG or xoshiro.

Comment: @Thorham - I have updated the answer, hopefully to be more clear, etc. As far as the recommendation of the RNGCryptoServiceProvider - it is recommended if the need is cryptographic security - algorithms like PCG, xoshiro, Mersenne Twister, etc are not cryptographically secure. As a further side note, neither PCG or xoshiro existed at the time I wrote this answer :)

Comment: Your answer is MUCH improved! And yes, you're right. Those generators I mentioned didn't exist yet. Guess I missed the posting date.

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler than that. If you can this method in a tight loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   Random ran = new Random();
   byte tmp;            
   tmp = (byte)ran.Next(10);
}
```

You might see the same number over and over. Make sure you create the Random object outside any sort of looping.

```
Random ran = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   byte tmp;            
   tmp = (byte)ran.Next(10);
}
```

That said, it is true that the crypto provider is better. But you're only getting randoms between 0 & 9 so how random does it have to be?

Comment: I am simulating a statistic  with 10% probability so i generate 0-10 and see how often is 0 generated

Comment: @Dominating: Be careful. You're actually generating numbers 0-9. 10 will never be generated as it is the exclusive upper limit.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider the random.org API

http://www.random.org/clients/http/