# Rolling Dice probability of dice value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a dice rolling game for which I am using the following logic. I want the dice values from 6 to 12 should fall in lesser probability. Based on the dice value the student Bonus point is increased. So higher the dice value higher the bonus point. So the dice value from 2 to 5 will fall frequently and the dice value from 6 to 12 should fall only for every 100th student. This is an windows application and each time the dice is rolled and the user gets the dice value the application is closed and again opened for another user to roll the dice. So how to track that the 100th student gets the dice value between 6 to 12..

```
for (Int32 i = 0; i < numberOfDice; i++)
{
    Int32 roll = rnd.Next(1, numberOfSides);
    total += roll;

    result.AppendFormat("Congrats..!!! You got Dice {0:00}:\t{1}\n", i + 1, roll);
}
```

Please help.
Any idea on how to do this. Please help.

Comment: Random isn't really that random :)
Look at this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152519/real-random-c-sharp-generator

Comment: Do these dice have more than six sides?

Comment: You could have a Monte Carlo method. If you roll 6/12 you then roll another die to see if you should reroll.

Answer (score 2):

what about sweepstakes? you can pregenerate an array of possible values, where number will be in array as many times as 1/probability. then you can simple use any kind of random from 0 to array length.

```
var sweeps = new List<int>();

for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        sweeps.Add(i);
    }
}

for (int i = 6; i <= 12; i++)
{
    sweeps.Add(i);
}

var count = sweeps.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDice; i++)
{
    int roll = sweeps[rnd.Next(1, count)];
    total += roll;

    result.AppendFormat("Congrats..!!! You got Dice {0:00}:\t{1}\n", i + 1, roll);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int RollLoadedDie(int numberOfSides)
{
    const lesserProbability = 50;
    int ret;
    bool keepValue;
    do
    {
        ret = rnd.Next(1, numberOfSides);
        if(ret == 6 || ret == 12)
            keepValue = rnd.Next(1, 100) > lesserProbability;
        else
            keepValue = true;
    }
    while(keepValue == false);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Any idea on how to do this. Please help.

Comment: Erm...this IS a Monte Carlo algorithm for generating a loaded die.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int RollDice(int numDice, int numSides)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numDice; i++)
    {
        int roll;
        if(rnd.NextDouble() < 0.01)
            roll = rnd.Next(6, numSides + 1);
        else
            roll = rnd.Next(1, 5 + 1);

        total += roll;

        result.AppendFormat("Congrats..!!! You got Dice {0:00}:\t{1}\n", i + 1, roll);
    }
    return total;
}
```

This code will, once every hundred times, roughly, generate a value from 6 to maxSides. If you want it to just be 6-12 regardless, you could try this.

```
public int RollDice(int numDice, int numSides)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numDice; i++)
    {
        int roll;
        if(rnd.NextDouble() < 0.01)
            roll = rnd.Next(6, Math.Min(12, numSides) + 1);
        else
        {
            roll = rnd.Next(1, numSides - (Math.Min(12, numSides) - 6 + 1) + 1);
            if(roll >= 6)
                roll += (Math.Min(12, numSides) - 6 + 1);
        }

        total += roll;

        result.AppendFormat("Congrats..!!! You got Dice {0:00}:\t{1}\n", i + 1, roll);
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int roleDice(int numberOfSides)
{ 
 // the chance in which the dice throws a value from 6   to 12

 int Large = rnd.Next(1,100) ; 
 for(int i =1 ; i < 101 ; i++)
 {
 if(i ==Large) // Only once for 100 times we throw a value between 7 , 12 included.
 keepValue = rnd.Next(7,12);

 else // For rest throw a value between 1 and 6
keepValue = rnd.Next(1,6);
}
return keepValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Random` generator is uniform. So, use three RNGs: one to decide whether it should generate a large value or a small value, and two for generating respectively the small values and large values.

```
var decider = new Random();
var largeRng = new Random();
var smallRng = new Random();

var deciderValue = decider.Next(1, 100);
int generatedValue;

if (deciderValue == 1) // will happen with probability 1/100
{
    generatedValue = largeRng.Next(6, 12);
}
else
{
    generatedValue = smallRng.Next(1, 5);
}
```

PS: If you use the same generator to decide what values to produce and then use it again to generate those values, like some answers, the generated small and large values will **NOT** be uniformly distributed.